# confirm alert box is displayed for 2 times in phone gap

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I am using notification.confirm in my iPhone application using phonegap.

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(e){
    buyDialogBox();
});


function buyDialogBox(){
   navigator.notification.confirm(
        getIndRestrictionText(),  // message
        onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
        'confirm alert Box',            // title
        'ok,Cancle'          // buttonLabels
   );
}

function onConfirm( button ){
    if( button == 1 ){
       alert("Ok button is clicked");
    }else{
       alert("cancel button is clicked");
    }
}
```

while button is clicked and we press the ok or cancel button then immediately confirm alert box is displayed for second time for very small amount of period.

I am wondering that why the confirm alert box is displayed for second time.

Please give me solution for that.

Comment: try this: $("#buttonId").click(function(e){
    
 if(e.handled !== true)
    {
  buyDialogBox();
  e.handled = true;
 }
 return false;
});

Comment: here, buyDialogBox() method is only called once.I have checked it using alert. But confirm alert box is displayed twice.

Comment: try this if(button == 1) { window.setTimeout("alert('ok button is licked');",1000); } else { window.setTimeout("alert('cancel button is clicked');",1000); }